# Azure blob storage returning 200 status before upload is finished causing a race condition

Tags: node.js, azure-blob-storage

I recently asked a question about uploading an image to Azure blob storage and got this working. Now I’m having a problem where Azure is returning a 200 status to the node server even though the blob isn’t finished uploading. This creates a problem where my node server then moves on and returns a 200 status to the front end which then tries to get the SASKey and display the image. Unfortunately, the file isn’t yet there and my front end gets a 404 error when trying to display the file. Using the console log, I can see that this is the problem. (Plus, if you just refresh the page, the file displays perfectly. So I know it was uploaded and valid.)

From what I’ve found in my research, it seems this is expected behavior from Azure. It sends the initial 200 status to indicate that the file was received and it’s being uploaded. But I can’t figure out a good way to keep my backend from continuing on while the upload is processing. I’ve used async / await on all the various pieces. But since Azure is essentially telling my backend that it’s done, the backend keeps going.

I’ve thought about putting in some code to make the function wait a second or two but that seems like a bad idea since there’s no way to know how long to wait and will slow down every single operation to the slowest possible speed to allow for the largest files to finish.

I also saw some references to using the doesBlobExist method.  My thought was to have the front end run that until it got a successful result. Again, seems like a bad way to go for some of the same reasons as above. Plus, it adds to the I/O computing required of Azure. Maybe not the cheapest route either.  Finally, I wasn't able to make this work and received an error that the function doesn't exist. I can't seem to find any solid documentation for using this via node.js.

I surely can’t be the first to come across this problem. Can anyone please help me with what I might be missing?

Thanks in advance for any thoughts you might share!

To try to explain further, the following is the significant code in the backend:

**The API route:**

```
app.post('/addNewBlob', async (req, res) => { 
   console.log('starting addNewBlob api') 

   let uploadResult = await bloboperations.uploadFile(req) 

   console.log('sending back to the frontend event service the new blob result: ', uploadResult) 

       res.send(uploadResult)  

})
```

**The significant part of the bloboperations.uploadFile function:**

```
const options = { blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: file.type } }; 

const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.uploadFile(filePath, options) 

console.log('this is the bloboperations/addBlob function result: ', uploadBlobResponse)
```

The next bit is the **console log results** in the backend. You can see that it’s sending a response back to the API route before Azure is finished uploading.

> starting addNewBlob api
> sending back to the frontend event service the new blob result:  undefined
>
> this is the bloboperations/addBlob function result:  {
>   etag: '"0x8D8FC5573C8FDA9"',
>   lastModified: 2021-04-10T19:18:41.000Z,
>   contentMD5: <Buffer d5 5b dd f8 d6 29 10 87 9e d9 f6 05 52 21 49 a8>,
>   clientRequestId: 'ec3361eb-b724-4f6b-b15b-da5485ef651b',
>   requestId: '07285764-a01e-00ad-233e-2ec5e9000000',
>   version: '2020-06-12',
>   versionId: undefined,
>   date: 2021-04-10T19:18:41.000Z,
>   isServerEncrypted: true,
>   encryptionKeySha256: undefined,
>   encryptionScope: undefined,
>   errorCode: undefined,
>   'content-length': '0',
>   server: 'Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0',
>   'x-ms-content-crc64': 'FjEzscJ7y9U=',
>   body: undefined
> }

Comment: try this:  let uploadResult = await bloboperations.uploadFile(req.file)

Comment: Thank you for the response. That breaks the upload completely. To clarify a little better, the upload itself is working as is. It uploads to Azure. The problem is having the rest of the app wait for the upload to finish. I can't find a way to know when it's done because Azure is sending a response before it's complete.

Comment: Ohh ok ok don't really know whats happening but try to put your code in try catch when using async await

Comment: Thank you. It's not shown in the code above but it is in a try catch. Again, the reason my app is not waiting for the upload to finish is because Azure is sending back a status 200 as soon as it gets the request (assuming the request if formatted properly.) There isn't an error being thrown. I need some work around. Wondering if anyone has used a doesBlobExist or exist method? If so, is there documentation? Any other thoughts about how to get the app to wait without slowing the app unnecessarily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Wondering if anyone has used a doesBlobExist or exist method? If so,
> is there documentation?

Yes, you can use `exists()` method to check whether it exists. It returns true if the Azure blob resource represented by this client exists; false otherwise.

code snippet:

```
const options = { blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: file.type } }; 

const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.uploadFile(filePath, options); 

const exist = await blockBlobClient.exists();
```

API document link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest#exists_BlobExistsOptions_

Comment: Thank you for the info. I was able to successfully use this method. However, I found that another problem I was having was related to the fact that I was using Formidable to parse the form with the file and field info. I also needed to wrap that in a promise to get everything working perfectly.